# How to use getElementById to get the elements in a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, getelementsbyname

I am wondering why in the following script comment 1 and comment 2 dosent work
I know that we can access directly element by id without passing by "form"
however am asking the question for educational purpose
Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>test</title>
 <script>
  function ulDisply()
  {
  //var element = document.myform.getElementsByName("name1")[0].value;//1
  //var element = document.myform.getElementsById("id1").value;//2
  //var element = document.myform.elements[0].value;//3
  var element = document.myform.d.value;//4
  document.write("you number is "+ element +"<br>");
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="myform">
  <input type="number" name="n" id="d">
  <input  type="submit" onclick="ulDisply()">  
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be the name, not the id. `document.myform.n.value;`

Comment: There is nothing with `name='name1'` and `id='id1'`

Answer (score 1):

Comment 1 :

> var element = document.myform.getElementsByName("name1")[0].value;

doesn't work because :

- there is no element named "name1".
- `getElementsByName` is defined in the `document` object

Comment 2 :

> var element = document.myform.getElementsById("id1").value;

doesn't work because :

- the right name of the function is `getElementById` and it's defined in the `document` object
- there is no element whose id is "id1"

When corrected, it works :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>test</title>
 <script>
  function ulDisply()
  {
  var element = document.getElementById("d").value;//2
    


  document.write("you number is "+ element +"<br>");
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="myform">
  <input type="number" name="n" id="d">
  <input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="ulDisply()">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Quentin getElementsByTagName is defined in HTMLElement. getElementsByName is not. Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
var element = document.getElementById("d").value;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the code to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <script>
            function ulDisply()
            {
            var element = document.getElementsByName("n")[0].value;//1
            //var element = document.getElementById("d").value;//2
            //var element = document.myform.elements[0].value;//3
            //var element = document.myform.d.value;//4
            document.write("you number is "+ element +"<br>");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform">
            <input type="number" name="n" id="d">
            <input  type="submit" onclick="ulDisply()">     
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```